# Customize wordpress comments

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I am working on my own plugin in wordpress, and i want to hook to comments in order to remove written comments, but still allow user to write them using the 'Leave a Reply' form, as displayed in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEqPV.png). (I will be displaying the comments at a different location)

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Try this help [ https://dfactory.eu/turn-off-disable-comments/ ]

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful.